# Misaligned buttons?

Tags: unity, 13.04, window

I have been installed `ubuntu-gnome` package, then modifying the Unity themes, and that button is misaligned now.

Before

[image]

After

[image]

What should I do?

Note I'm using 13.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it using Unity Tweak Tool...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command:

```
$ gconftool-2 --set "/apps/metacity/general/button_layout" --type string "close,minimize,maximize:"
```

Comment: Didn't worked, though.

Comment: Alright.. I have a Plan B

Answer (score 0):

Open the dconf editor. Navigate to the apps > metacity > general option in the left side window and then locate the button_layout option in the right side main window. Double click this option and set its value to "close,maximize,minimize:menu" without the "'s.

Comment: Didn't find `metacity`...